# How can I protect my included php files from direct access?

Tags: php, include

My script...

### index.php

```
DEFINE('DIR', 'http://www.example.com');
DEFINE('IN_PAGE', TRUE);

INCLUDE DIR . ('/incl/header.php');
INCLUDE DIR . ('/incl/content.php');
INCLUDE DIR . ('/incl/footer.php');
```

### /incl/header.php

```
if (!defined('IN_PAGE'))
{
    header("Status: 403 Forbidden");
    exit('<B>403 Forbidden</B>');
}
```

### Visiting index.php

> Warning:
>   include(http://www.example.com/incl/header.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open
>   stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1
>   403 Forbidden in
>   /public_html/incl/index-incl.php
>   on line 4
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]:
>   Failed opening
>   'http://www.example.com/incl/header.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php') in
>   /public_html/incl/index-incl.php
>   on line 4

---

It works kinda, if I try accessing the file directly I get "Forbidden" message like I wanted.. But I can't include it in my script.. even though I'm pretty sure I followed phpBB's dev wiki correctly.

I'm pretty damn novice, so your help is greatly appreciated!  =]

Comment: The best way is to put your include files outside the document root or to configure your server not to execute scripts in the directory they're in.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't include it in my script"? In what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal way would be to place your include files outside of the webroot.

This is not always possible so make sure your include files don't 'run' any code by themselves. Adopt an Object Oriented approach where either a file contains runnable code, or it's a class file that doesn't do anything by itself.

Another alternative would be to change the extensions of your include files (to .inc for instance) and deny these from direct access with htaccess.

As a pro-tip: when you're including files always include with an absolute path:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/template.inc");
// __FILE__ is the diskpath of the current file
```

and not:

```
include("includes/template.inc");
```

This will save you many headaches.

And as the other guys said, never include files from another webserver (http://), this means you're doing something fundamentally wrong :P

Comment: I thought I was doing so, using `DIR . ('/incl/footer.php');`
DIR is the path, because the sites not live, and so the path will change when it becomes life, thus I will need to redefine DIR.

Comment: I see now.. Thanks.. I don't understand why it wouldn't work with the absolute path, it's working.. I created two different defines, one for the included files, and one for images and such.. since `__FILE__` will not work if I'm trying to call an image or css file.

Comment: I meant I did not understand why it didn't work when I provided the URL www.example.com and not /public_html/username/domain/ (the diskpath)

Answer (score 1):

Go for use of [htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: he could block `*.inc.php` files from beeing served

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include like
INCLUDE ('http://www.example.com/incl/header.php');
basically

Change the dir to
DEFINE('DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

Or something similar so it's not using a domain in the include path which then means the include is done locally.

Answer (score 0):

you tries to include a remote file `DEFINE('DIR', 'http://www.example.com');` so your server actually calls the url, gets the error and shows it
use relative path eg. `DEFINE('DIR', '/');` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, `include` uses the local path of files, not the urls. You need to know what is the root path of your files in your account, like `/home/your_account/public_html/`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.. I should pay more close attention to the manual. :]